# Optimistic Locking Exception using Grails GORM and MySQL

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.4.4 and MySQL database. We are trying to clone a group of tables in our database having parent-child relationship. For example we have a table author with its child table book and book having foreign key fk_book pointing to author.

We retrieve the hierarchy through `Author.get(id)`, the cloning author, its associated book and save using `clonedAuthor.save(flush:true)`. We have hierarchy of several tables like this, some having OneToOne and some having OneToMany relationships. In database, the foreign key constraints are given as ON DELETE NO ACTION.

The problem is when invoked. It is throwing Optimistic Locking Failure Exception

```
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction.
```

I am not getting which transaction is updating the row since we have only one transaction (only one hit).

Comment: please just post the full error message, the above error message is missing important info, it does not show on which domain object is this happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting same problem when *modifying db data using mysql console while some of the data is already fetched to the hibernate session*.

---

***why is this happening?***

*Just simple, the data in db and in hibernate session are out of sync.*

Also if you are putting the domain object ( or any related domain object) in session try  to re-attach the object(`obj.attach()`) before calling `save`,`delete`..

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 solutions: merge() or attach() before save()... or mapping the entity with version false.